# I am trying to input two values into my command line in java. I am getting this error. Why?

Tags: java

```
    String fileName1 = args[0]; //LINE 14 i am getting error here
    String fileName2 = args[1]; 


    File file1 = new File(fileName1);
    File file2 = new File(fileName2);
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(file1);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(file2);
```

This is my piece of code in my main function. Whenever I try to run my program I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
   at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:14)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you running your program? **What** command line are you entering?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch i think consoles? Sorry i am new to java.

Comment: Please show the exact command you're entering into the command line in order to run the program.

Comment: An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `0` makes no sense, especially because index 1 wasn't out of bounds...

Comment: @JackKirby Java stops execution at the first line which produces an exception. `args[1]` never runs, so it doesn't have an opportunity to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your commandline must be like this: `java -jar jarfile.jar firstString secondString`
You must provide 2 string in your command. The `firstString` and `secondString`

Comment: Yes, but @Sperm Monkey is asking for command line problem.

Comment: They dont let me write anything in the command line. There area just happens

Comment: @SpermMonkey Who is "They"? And how are you even running the application from the command line if you can't enter a command? Please explain in your question exactly how you're running the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to run on command line. You must go to Run Configuration.. -> and find your main class -> input the string1 and string2 as my picture.
[image]

In this pic, Tray is my class have main function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling it a 'command line' instead of 'console'.
This is an example of a command line:

[image: Command Line (or Command Prompt in Windows]

This is an example of a console, assuming you are using Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse Console]

So, you're trying to enter the file locations in the console after the program is already running but the Java program expects it the moment you run it, via the `args[]` array in the `main` method. Hence, the error. To resolve that you should use Tuyen's answer.